# How to use VI18n in vue library

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create custom vue library to use it in different projects using vue-cli-service

In package.JSON

```
build-lib: vue-cli-service build --target lib src/init.js
```

And the init.js

```
import DummyLib from './components/DummyLib.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import {english} from './vi18n/english'

Vue.use(VueI18n)
const messages = {
  en: english
}
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  messages // set locale messages
})
export default DummyLib
```

When i build it and using the library in the different project, it is not working.

How do i import **vue-i18n** in the library?

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to pass in the initiated `i18n` plugin to the Vue instance that you're creating.

So you're doing everything correct already! Now the last step would be to add the `i18n` variable to the Vue instance, like this:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  i18n
})
```

If you're initialising the i18n plugin in a separate module, then make sure to export the instance

```
export const i18n = new VueI18n({ ... })
```

And in your `main.js` / `main.ts` file

```
import { i18n } from './i18n'

// ... rest of the setup

new Vue({ i18n })
```

Comment: Hi, I have added every thing in main.js and if i do `npm run serve` it is working. But if i do `npm run build-lib` to build the library, it is not working. `init.js` is the entry point file in the build-lib and main.js file wont execute. As you see i am exporting the component in init.js. How can i create the vue instance and how do i export component if i create the vue instance in the init.js?